# Composer post-install-cmd not running with git hook

Tags: git, laravel, phantomjs, composer-php

for some reason my post-install-cmd doesn't seem to run when composer is run from my deploy hook.

If i run `composer install` via ssh on the box immediately after then the install process runs again, but does run the post install script.

For clarity, it is the 'jakoch/phantomjs-installer' that i want to run.

As you see, my composer is set up and ready.

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "5.0.*",
        "jakoch/phantomjs-installer": "1.9.8",
        "illuminate/html": "~5.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database",
            "app/libraries",
            "app/Models"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize",
            "PhantomInstaller\\Installer::installPhantomJS"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize",
            "PhantomInstaller\\Installer::installPhantomJS"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\"",
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

And the output from the post receive hook runs the composer install as below:

```
remote: Checking composer.json for Composer dependency... 
remote: Warning: This development build of composer is over 30 days old. It is recommended to update it by running "/var/lib/openshift/5555f3255973ca3b9c00018a/php/usr/bin/composer self-update" to get the latest version.
remote: Loading composer repositories with package information
remote: Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
remote:   - Installing react/promise (v2.2.0)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing guzzlehttp/streams (3.0.0)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing guzzlehttp/ringphp (1.0.7)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (5.2.0)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing vlucas/phpdotenv (v1.1.0)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing symfony/var-dumper (v2.6.7)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing symfony/translation (v2.6.7)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing symfony/security-core (v2.6.7)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing symfony/routing (v2.6.7)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing symfony/process (v2.6.7)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v2.6.7)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher (v2.6.7)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing psr/log (1.0.0)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing symfony/debug (v2.6.7)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing symfony/http-kernel (v2.6.7)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing symfony/finder (v2.6.7)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing symfony/console (v2.6.7)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v5.4.0)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing nikic/php-parser (v1.3.0)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing jakub-onderka/php-console-color (0.1)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter (v0.3.1)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing dnoegel/php-xdg-base-dir (0.1)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing psy/psysh (v0.4.4)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing nesbot/carbon (1.19.0)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing mtdowling/cron-expression (v1.0.4)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing monolog/monolog (1.13.1)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing league/flysystem (1.0.3)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing jeremeamia/superclosure (2.1.0)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing ircmaxell/password-compat (v1.0.4)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing doctrine/inflector (v1.0.1)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing danielstjules/stringy (1.9.0)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing symfony/filesystem (v2.6.7)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing classpreloader/classpreloader (1.3.0)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing laravel/framework (v5.0.31)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing illuminate/html (v5.0.0)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing jakoch/phantomjs-installer (1.9.8)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock (2.0.4)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing symfony/yaml (v2.6.7)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing sebastian/recursion-context (1.0.0)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing sebastian/exporter (1.2.0)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing sebastian/diff (1.3.0)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing sebastian/comparator (1.1.1)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing doctrine/instantiator (1.0.4)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing phpspec/prophecy (v1.4.1)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing phpspec/php-diff (v1.0.2)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing phpspec/phpspec (2.2.0)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing phpunit/php-token-stream (1.4.1)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing sebastian/version (1.0.5)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing sebastian/global-state (1.0.0)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing sebastian/environment (1.2.2)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing phpunit/php-text-template (1.2.0)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects (2.3.1)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing phpunit/php-timer (1.0.5)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing phpunit/php-file-iterator (1.4.0)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing phpunit/php-code-coverage (2.0.16)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote:   - Installing phpunit/phpunit (4.6.6)
remote:     Loading from cache
remote: 
remote: symfony/var-dumper suggests installing ext-symfony_debug ()
remote: symfony/translation suggests installing symfony/config ()
remote: symfony/security-core suggests installing symfony/expression-language (For using the expression voter)
remote: symfony/security-core suggests installing symfony/validator (For using the user password constraint)
remote: symfony/routing suggests installing doctrine/annotations (For using the annotation loader)
remote: symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/config (For using the all-in-one router or any loader)
remote: symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/expression-language (For using expression matching)
remote: symfony/event-dispatcher suggests installing symfony/dependency-injection ()
remote: symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/browser-kit ()
remote: symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/class-loader ()
remote: symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/config ()
remote: symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/dependency-injection ()
remote: psy/psysh suggests installing ext-pdo-sqlite (The doc command requires SQLite to work.)
remote: monolog/monolog suggests installing aws/aws-sdk-php (Allow sending log messages to AWS services like DynamoDB)
remote: monolog/monolog suggests installing doctrine/couchdb (Allow sending log messages to a CouchDB server)
remote: monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-amqp (Allow sending log messages to an AMQP server (1.0+ required))
remote: monolog/monolog suggests installing graylog2/gelf-php (Allow sending log messages to a GrayLog2 server)
remote: monolog/monolog suggests installing raven/raven (Allow sending log messages to a Sentry server)
remote: monolog/monolog suggests installing rollbar/rollbar (Allow sending log messages to Rollbar)
remote: monolog/monolog suggests installing ruflin/elastica (Allow sending log messages to an Elastic Search server)
remote: monolog/monolog suggests installing videlalvaro/php-amqplib (Allow sending log messages to an AMQP server using php-amqplib)
remote: league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-aws-s3-v2 (Allows you to use S3 storage with AWS SDK v2)
remote: league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 (Allows you to use S3 storage with AWS SDK v3)
remote: league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-azure (Allows you to use Windows Azure Blob storage)
remote: league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-cached-adapter (Flysystem adapter decorator for metadata caching)
remote: league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-copy (Allows you to use Copy.com storage)
remote: league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-dropbox (Allows you to use Dropbox storage)
remote: league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-eventable-filesystem (Allows you to use EventableFilesystem)
remote: league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-rackspace (Allows you to use Rackspace Cloud Files)
remote: league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-sftp (Allows you to use SFTP server storage via phpseclib)
remote: league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-webdav (Allows you to use WebDAV storage)
remote: league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-ziparchive (Allows you to use ZipArchive adapter)
remote: league/flysystem suggests installing predis/predis (Allows you to use Predis for caching)
remote: laravel/framework suggests installing aws/aws-sdk-php (Required to use the SQS queue driver and SES mail driver (~2.4).)
remote: laravel/framework suggests installing doctrine/dbal (Required to rename columns and drop SQLite columns (~2.4).)
remote: laravel/framework suggests installing iron-io/iron_mq (Required to use the iron queue driver (~1.5).)
remote: laravel/framework suggests installing league/flysystem-aws-s3-v2 (Required to use the Flysystem S3 driver (~1.0).)
remote: laravel/framework suggests installing league/flysystem-rackspace (Required to use the Flysystem Rackspace driver (~1.0).)
remote: laravel/framework suggests installing pda/pheanstalk (Required to use the beanstalk queue driver (~3.0).)
remote: laravel/framework suggests installing predis/predis (Required to use the redis cache and queue drivers (~1.0).)
remote: phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock suggests installing dflydev/markdown (~1.0)
remote: phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock suggests installing erusev/parsedown (~1.0)
remote: phpspec/phpspec suggests installing phpspec/nyan-formatters (~1.0 – Adds Nyan formatters)
remote: sebastian/global-state suggests installing ext-uopz (*)
remote: phpunit/php-code-coverage suggests installing ext-xdebug (>=2.2.1)
remote: phpunit/phpunit suggests installing phpunit/php-invoker (~1.1)
```

But never installs the actual file, and i need to ssh in and run `composer install` manually, which works:

```
[teampro-propduck.rhcloud.com repo]\> composer install
Warning: This development build of composer is over 30 days old. It is recommended to update it by running "/var/lib/openshift/5555f3255973ca3b9c00018a/php/usr/bin/composer self-update" to get the latest version.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
Generating optimized class loader
Compiling common classes
  - Installing phantomjs (1.9.8)
    Loading from cache
```

Comment: Hey Ryk, i'm not sure why the `phantomjs-installer` is not triggered by the hook. Could you run Composer in verbose mode (from the Git hook) to get some more details on whats going on: `composer install -vvv`?

Comment: Unfortunately it seems like composer is called by openshift by using a marker file, so i can't control the output on the hook that isn't working. Workaround so far is to just call `composer update` at a later stage in the hook that i do have control over. Seems to be working, but seems like such a waste!

Comment: Ah, ok. Yes, running `composer update` is an unnecessary additional step. -- Guessing around: Is `php artisan optimize` executed? Is this a `1.9.8` issue (try to raise to `2.0.0`) - 2.0.0 will not install Phantom, because the binaries are not released, but at least you can test if the installer is executed. --  I can not reproduce the issue and without debug infos, we are stuck. Feel free to open a bugreport over at https://github.com/jakoch/phantomjs-installer maybe someone else runs into or has the same issue and is able to help. Thanks, Jens

Comment: Yeah i agree, i'm going to try and wait until the linux 2.0.0 version is released, then see what happens. Workaround is fine for now, just adds an extra minute to my deploy script (not the end of the world). I will of course update this when i do get to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 1):

Answer so far is to run an additional `composer update` at a later point in the deploy hook. So essentially it runs twice.

It's definitely a workaround, rather than a fix, but might get people moving rather than the 3 days i spent completely stuck on it.

Will update if i get any further with a proper fix.